# Having difficulty simulating Parallel capacitor inverter at falstad.com

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

Here is the circuit: [from Falstad.com](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2031%205%2043%0Al%2096%20464%20208%20336%200%200.001%20-3.1981714561621843%0Ar%20512%20336%20640%20304%200%2050%0Ar%20512%20144%20640%20224%200%2050%0Ar%20912%20224%20912%20304%200%20200%0AR%20160%2048%2096%2048%200%202%2060%20125%20125%203.141592653589793%200.1%0AR%20256%2032%20256%20-48%200%200%2040%20125%20125%200%200.5%0At%20208%2048%20256%2048%200%201%20-249.999999999899%20-37.652236124768486%20100%0A177%20352%20336%20208%20368%201%2033.563358821716925%200.8557504319798355%200.01%200.008199999999999999%2022%0A177%20352%20144%20208%2096%201%2038.50383578628705%200.8516721404560883%200.01%200.008199999999999999%2022%0Aw%20640%20256%20640%20272%200%0Aw%20464%20480%20640%20272%200%0A406%20640%20224%20912%20400%202%200.05%200.9%201,1:2%203%20-1.7114626592327447%201.8137856056168902%200.000905157183344068%20%0AR%20464%20480%20464%20544%200%200%2040%20125%200%200%200.5%0Ag%2096%20464%2096%20512%200%0Aw%20208%20144%20208%20336%200%0Ac%20512%20144%20512%20336%202%201e-8%204.937473104601139%0Ad%20512%20336%20352%20336%202%20default%0Ad%20512%20144%20352%20144%202%20default%0Ac%20352%20144%20352%20336%202%202e-8%204.940476964570124%0Ar%20160%2048%20208%2048%200%201000%0Ar%20256%2064%20256%20112%200%201000%0AR%20256%20416%20256%20480%200%202%2060%20125%20125%200%200.1%0Ar%20256%20368%20256%20416%200%20100%0Ao%2018%2064%200%204099%20320%203.2%200%202%2018%203%0A)

The circuit crudely converts 125vdc to 250vac. The main idea of the circuit is that: the thyristors will be pulsed 180 degrees apart, 60hz. the capacitor will charge to twice of 125vdc every cycle (125vdc from the dc source + 125vdc induced on the other half of the primary coil) and help one thyristor to cut off its currents, while another thyristor is being turned on. Then the capacitor can again charge to twice of 125vdc, this time, the other way.

I am having difficulty in the following 3 areas:

- how to set up a thyristor, I have failed spectacularly. current in the thyristor just travels everywhere, not sure if the website's simulation is doing it right.
- the voltage across A and K of my thyristors are way more than 1v across. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I was suspecting the internal resistance of thyristor was too high.
- The circuit is just not working. both thyristors are conducting. One conducting is supposed to shut the other one off.

Comment: With your setup, I was able to get something resembling a sine wave at the output by changing the duty cycles of both square wave generators to 50 and increasing the capacitors to 100 uF and 10 uF. Also, a thyristor cuts off when the current flowing through it dips below a certain threshold - if they both start conducting, it becomes hard to turn them both off. I think you might want to look into a different component.

Comment: Falstad sucks. Use a proper simulator https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html

Comment: @Tri yes, the capacitors' value does matter a lot. I have to stick with Thyristors because I am trying to simulate a real world circuit and make sense of it. So, you don't see any problems with my thyristor "pulse circuit setup", they look ok?

Comment: @BruceAbbott my circuit knowledge is barely university circuit 101 and 102 level, I am not into design precise circuit. I am more interested just to have rough visual ideas of what a waveform would look like in a circuit. Could you share more experience or reason why Falstad is no good?